# Как показать html страницу?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, webview, mingw

Как на `windows, qt 5.12.1 (MSVC 2015, 32 бита), MinGW 7.3.0 32/64 bit` показать одну простую `html` страницу со стилями `css`? 
Модуля `webenginewidgets` на сколько я понял для mingw нет, он есть для vs. У QT QLabel или другие виджеты могут показывать html страницу, но как связать QLabel c html файлом и со стилями?
Для открытия html-файла с картинками из ресурсов, необходимо добавить сам html-файл и все ресурсы под одним префиксом.
Далее:

```
QTextBrowser *b = new QTextBrowser;
b->setSource(QUrl(":/doc/Doc/Main.html"));
b->show();
```

Так картинки и другие ресурсы будут подключены. Но вот со стилями так и не получилось.

Comment: QTextEdit / QTextBrowser / QWebEngineView?

Comment: @gil9red как связать с html страницей и со стилями?
ну у меня допустим в ресурсах есть 2 файла: html, css. что дальше делать?

Comment: Можно, например, внедрить в html стили из css

Comment: я об этом думал, но это если буду обречен, то так и сделаю. А хорошего способа нет?

Comment: Если у вас файлы html и css локальные, то думаю css подхватится в html если в html будет указан путь, например `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mysite.css">` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494473/5909792). Кст, QLabel поддерживает простой набор тегов, поэтому не уверен, что вам стили отобразит

Comment: `QTextBrowser *b = new QTextBrowser;b->setSource(QUrl(":/doc/Doc/Main.html"));b->show();` ничего не показывает

Comment: А так `QUrl("qrc:/doc/Doc/Main.html")`? // https://forum.qt.io/topic/1494/universal-solution-for-resource-prefix/7

Comment: Так уже и html открывает, и в них картинки использует. Но стили нет

Comment: А стили они в самом HTML захаркодены?

Comment: в html-файле присутствует такая строчка: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
`

Comment: 1) Не думаю, что тот поймет что этот файл должен быть не в папке с exe лежать, а в qrc 2) судя по этой теме https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/1619-CSS-in-QTextBrowser `QTextBrowser doesn't handle external css.`, поэтому можно попробовать захаркодить (например програмно вставить в html стили) и через setHtml отобразить 3) похоже, проще всего будет с QWebEngineView работать

Comment: видимо придется, спасибо